# Test events were not received - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no idea how to test and I was following a tutorial.I am trying to run:

```
package name.company.sunshine.app.data;

import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

public class TestPractice extends AndroidTestCase {
     /*
       This gets run before every test.
     */
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void testThatDemonstratesAssertions() throws Throwable {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 3;
        int c = 5;
        int d = 10;

        assertEquals("X should be equal", a, c);
        assertTrue("Y should be true", d > a);
        assertFalse("Z should be false", a == b);

        if (b > d) {
            fail("XX should never happen");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

but I get somewhere in the bottom left corner, in the console `Test events were not received`. What am I doing wrong ? Should I run something else ?

Comment: Just a though, have you tried removing the `throws Exception` from the test function? Try handling it in your function. I am not familiar with Unit Testing on android, but in standard junit testing, exception need to be explicitly declared to the unit tester. `@Test(expected=Exception.class)`

Comment: I haven't, but this is exactly what they are doing in the tutorial and for some reason he doesn't get `Test events were not received`. What should I remove and where should I add it ?

Comment: Try changing this line: `public void testThatDemonstratesAssertions() throws Throwable {` to this: `public void testThatDemonstratesAssertions()  {`, and handle your exception in the test case, if applicable. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Use `JUnit 4` and remove `AndroidTestCase`.

Comment: @MattClark Udacity tutorials for sunshine app

Comment: @MattClark Did that and I get the same message `Test events were not received`

Comment: @BogdanDaniel what does your run configuration look like in Android Studio? Basically Android Studio is not finding your class on it's test classpath, it might also be an issue with your build.gradle file

Comment: I'm running into this issue if I try running the test with the Gradle run configuration.  If I run things with JUnit run configuration it works fine.  Haven't figured out why this happens yet.

Comment: Even if I run it with JUnit I get another error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter`

Comment: @BogdanDaniel if you want to run them as JUnit3 tests, simply replace `extends AndroidTestCase` with `extends TestCase` and import `junit.framework.TestCase` although I highly recommend using JUnit4

Comment: to expand on @JaredBurrows answer: what you are testing ultimately has nothing to do with Android. Try writing plain old JUnit tests instead.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel For those who want to run test cases http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/07/android-how-to-run-instrumentation.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run your test select the Android Test option.

[image: Screen Shot]

The JUnit and Gradle options should not be used for this type of test.

Comment: Thanks man, it's going me crazy. I was only receiving 'test events were not received' but your answer saved my live

Answer (score 3):

I am doing the course too and ended up with the same problem.

After an hour of tinkering I think I found the solution.

Don't try to run the the test cases from the whole package as they did in the video; you have to **run it from a single class and choose the AndroidTest option**. It does not work with the Gradle option.

See picture attached.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6utLv.png]

Comment: If I connect my phone and run them like that I saw that it works. I just thought that I can run them through Gradle. Even if I try the JUnit option I end up with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter` .

Comment: I also get the same error message when trying to run with JUnit

Answer (score 2):

For me, another test was not compiling with an error but the error was not obvious to see. I fixed the error and the tests ran after that.

Comment: Also, if the test is in another file and doesn't compile, the error won't show unless the file is opened, at which point the IDE will show the compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this problem after making two changes.

**uncheck `use in-process build` in Settings -> Build Tools -> Compiler**
Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172162

**force Gradle to re-run all tasks by updating your run configurations.
Add --rerun-tasks to the Script Parameters.**

Source: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/

Answer (score 0):

This solution is tested in android studio 1.5.1

If you have problem with tests in android studio because use in-process build disappeared, include the following:

```
<project-folder>
|-- .idea
    |-- workspace.xml
```

Just add the following component at the very top, just inside the project tag:

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="AndroidGradleBuildConfiguration">
    <option name="USE_EXPERIMENTAL_FASTER_BUILD" value="false" />
  </component>
  ...

</project>
```

Comment: I tried this and it works sometimes. Others, it shows same error.

Comment: You should also add the `--rerun-tasks` command to the script parameters of testing target

Answer (score 0):

In case someone with some newer version of AS will land on this thread:
I had similar problem with AS Giraffe/Hedgehog, and I had to check option "Force test tasks execution" in run config:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

just as Matt Accola sayd, if you already selected the gradle option and cant find that sub menu in his answer, u will need to go to run >> Edit Configuration... and then under the Gradle sub menu, delete the items (TestPractice & others if existed) and then re do the test by selecting the  AnroidTest.