# basic android unit testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle

I am using `Android Studio` and I wrote an ultra basic test for the `MAinActivity` class. I inherited `MainActivityTest` from `extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>` and I want to test

```
private MainActivity mMainActivityTest;
public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull("mMainActivityTest is null", mMainActivityTest);
    }
```

using `gradle` unit testing, without having to launch any emulator.

When I run the test, I get no red or green color bar, and whatever I choose `assertNotNull` or `assertNull`, I always get

```
External tasks execution finished 'cleanTest test --tests "com.my.app.MainActivityTest.testPreconditions"
```

how can I do correct unit test ?

Comment: have you tried any breakpoint? It seems your `@Test` annotation is missing

Comment: @KevinWallis I have indeed `@Test` annotation but it does not change anything. I notice there is a  log window with `Test events were not received `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` app level add to dependencies:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Put your test in directory:
src/test/java

Then your simple test, for example:

```
public class MainActivityTest(){
@Test
    public void testInitialAlwaysPasses(){
        assert true;
    }
}
```

Run it and you will see green lines and all the output. This is the basic Unit Test. For Instrumentation test you need to put your test in directory: src/androidTest/java. (Much easier is to right click in class you want to test and select Goto->test. It will create the test class for you). From here it will be easier to continue! Good luck!

Comment: I tried this : created a `src/test/java` folder, I implemented the quick method you propose, and I have still the same message. I get a message `External tasks execution finished 'cleanTest test --tests "com.my.app.MainActivityTest.testInitialAlwaysPasses`, with `Test events were not received `, with a grey bar instead of green or red. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Maybe you did not select the correct configuration ? Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30315572/2031068

Comment: I am precisely looking for gradle unit testing, without having to launch any emulator. How can I know which tests can pass with `gradle` ?

Comment: choose JUnit - it will testCompile for local unit tests only

Comment: sorry to bother you, I don't really understand, I already put in my code `import org.junit.Test;`. Do you mean `assertEquals(true, true);` can not be tested with `gradle`, I must use the emulator ?

Comment: no, you don't. There are two kinds of tests - local and Instrumentation. If you do local - you don't need emulator. AssertEquals(true, true) doesn't need emulator